# How to call different method in different Controllers in MVC Url.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, url.action

In my View I am using this form method:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")">
```

So "Index" is method in Controller - UserA:

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchParameters parameters, UserModel userModel)
```

My question is, how to add in this same View new form method, where I want to call action in different Controller, so I would for example call ... action="@Url.Action("Index2") ... Where Index2 is ActionResult Index2 ... in Controller - UserB.

Thanks for explanation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that takes a controller name as the second parameter, so you should be able to copy your existing code and add that second parameter:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index", "UserB")">
```

By the way, you can simplify your code even further by using the `HtmlHelper` [`BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) extension method, which has the [same overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index")) {
    // form fields here
}
```

and

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "UserB")) {
    // form fields here
}
```

That will render your `<form>` structure for you.

Comment: You're welcome! I also added a suggestion about how to render your forms -- there are some built-in helpers for that as well.